# How does one verify that the app store version of an open source app is running the same code?

Tags: android

There are many "open source" apps like K-9 mail on the android app store. If I compile and build the source code myself, I can be sure that the resulting apk, will indeed do what the source code says it will do.

But how can I verify, that the apk submitted to the store is actually the result of compiling the same source ? What is to stop the makers of k9 of inserting malicious code in the version submitted to the app store ? I don't see any hash, or other way of verifying the source.

(K-9 is just an example).

Answer (score 1):

Compare the contents of the APKs: the one you pull off the device (that you got from the Play Store or wherever) and the one that you compiled yourself. If the compiled classes differ, then there may be cause for deeper investigation. It's possible the differences come from differences in compilers, bytecode converters, or obfuscator settings. Or, it's possible that the differences are indicative of "malicious code". That work is up to you.

Or, use a store like F-Droid that compiles from source itself.

Or, just use the version that you compiled from source yourself.

Comment: I am aware I can compile the source myself. But if one cannot verify if the compiled apk is the result of compiling the same source code, the fact that the source code is open source isn't useful to the end user, and isn't a good enough reason to download (since effectively you need to trust it as much as proprietary software as its already compiled) - unless the end user can compile the source himself, which most people don't know how to do. Even me! :D Likewise a phone with cyanogenmod preinstalled could behave in ways different from the open source code that you compile yourself... XD